# How to show Pagenumber on \listoffigures and \listoftables?

Tags: header-footer, listoffigures, listoftables

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, %openright, 
toc=listof, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib} %Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage[linktoc=all,hidelinks]{hyperref} %Verlinkungen
\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} %header

%header
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark{section}
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{Seite\enspace\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\KOMAoptions{open=any}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\listoffigures %Abbildungsverzeichnis
\thispagestyle{plain}
\listoftables %Tabellenverzeichnis
\thispagestyle{plain}

\cleardoublepage
\KOMAoptions{open=right}
\pagestyle{headings}

\end{document}
```

so what i tried to receive here is an output where i have my usual headers on each normal page but just a plain pagenumber (in Roman style) on the pages of my list of figure and list of tables, but what i got is no pagenumbers on the list pages, even though i got the pagenumbers in the TOC. Neither of these lists has more than one page so i don't know, if the pagenumber would be shown after the first page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with KOMA budle, but I belive that it support `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`. The first one put imidiately after `begin{document}, and latter one before your main text (maybe before `KOMAoptions{...}`.

Comment: `\clearscrheadfoot` clears everything, i.e. the page numbers as well

Comment: @Zarko Neither `report` nor `scrreprt` provide the `\...matter` business.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer He set them after clearing everything.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Yes, I see that, but anyway, they aren't there ... so it's perhaps some `\thispagestyle{empty}` inherent in `\listoftoc` stuff?

Comment: You forgot ä Sternsche ;-) `\ohead*{Seite\enspace\pagemark}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Apologies, he didn't set them. ^^^^^^

Comment: @christian hupfer: i tried repositioning the \clearscrheadfoot and moved it right before the \cleardoublepage which gets me two new problems: 1. the pagenumber in the lists appear now but they are mispositioned and you only see half of them because they go under the bottom border. 2. my headers don't have the pagenumber now anymore.

Comment: @johannes_b: what does the "sternsche" - as you call it - do there?  ;) i mean my headers work, so why change that?

Comment: You wanted the pagenumber on the list-pages, right? The first page is set using pagestyle `plain` by default (chapterstart). The asterisk definesto put the pagenumber on plain pages as well. *cf.* [Wo sind Kopf und Fußzeile bei Kapitelstart?](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/6302/wo-sind-kopfzeile-und-fuzeile-bei-kapitelstart)

Comment: well that's a good start, it actually worked, tank you! but now i see the pagenumbers on the list pages where they are supposed to stand when i use headers. but i actually want them to appear in the bottom middle of the page and i don't want the word "Seite" to appear there. Can you provide a solution for that?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you forgot to ping me. Found this question by coincidence. It is a bit unclear to me, why you want a different output. Should the page number be at the bottom of the page for chapter-start pages as well?

Comment: @Johannes_B i forgot my own question somehow. But I would still want the Problem to be solved if possible. I simply want another output, because I think it would look better. Can you tell me how to put the Roman page numbers in the TOC, \listoffigures and \listoftables parts in the bottom middle while using the headers for the rest of the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that does what you want to achieve.

First, the header and footer are set up for the lists, later everything is cleared and once more, the stuff is set up for the main part.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, %openright, 
toc=listof, BCOR=5mm, bibliography=totoc, parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
%\automark{section}%JB Are you sure?
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\usepackage[linktoc=all,hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\KOMAoptions{open=any}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{Seite\enspace\pagemark}
\ihead{\headmark}
\KOMAoptions{open=right}

\foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Walzing}
    \blindtext
    \captionof{figure}{Figure \x}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure \x}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure \x}
    \section{Wombat}
    \Blindtext[4][3]
    \captionof{table}{Table \x}
    \captionof{table}{Table \x}
    \captionof{table}{Table \x}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, we are getting very close! It did pretty much what i wanted except one thing: the Roman numbers are on absolute bottom end of the pages so if i'm going to print the document, the printer won't be able to print those numbers i guess. Is it possible to move them like 1cm higher?

Comment: Please run the code as posted and tell me where the page numbers appear. Do you get any warnings? With which page does the roman numbering end, how many pages are there in total?

Comment: okay, your example works fine and the roman page numbers appear centered 2cm away from the bottom margin. Just in my document they appear right at bottom margin. i don't know why that is, but i think i will figure it out on my own. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Max  A [simple algorithm](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) will show you the source. (hint: click the link)